# How do I input a custom scalar in a query Mutation using Apollo Playground

Tags: graphql

Using Apollo Playground to test a mutation that uses an input Type object that contains a custom scalar. The field is lastWatched that is custom scalar type of Date.  Maybe there is a problem in the resolver for Date or I just can't figure out the correct syntax to use in Playground.

My custom scalar is called Date.  Here is my resolver code for Date.

NOTE:  Resolver code has been corrected as the problem was in the function: parseLiteral(ast).

```
    Date: new GraphQLScalarType({
    name: 'Date',
    description: 'Date custom scalar type',
    parseValue(value) {
      console.log('Date scalar parse:', value);
      return dayjs(value); // value from the client
    },
    serialize(value) {
      console.log('Date scalar serialize:', value);
      return dayjs(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); // value sent to the client
    },
    parseLiteral(ast) {
      console.log('Date scalar parseLit:', ast);
      if (ast.kind === Kind.STRING) {
        return dayjs(ast.value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') || null; // ast value is always in string format
      }
      return null;
    }
  })
```

My schema for the create mutation mutation.

```
    extend type Mutation {
    createPlaybackPosition(fields: CreatePlaybackPositionInput): PlaybackPositionResponse
    updatePlaybackPosition(filename: ID!): PlaybackPositionResponse
    deletePlaybackPosition(filename: ID!): PlaybackPositionResponse
  }

  input CreatePlaybackPositionInput {
    "pseudo primary key"
    filename: ID!
    "in seconds"
    position: Int!
    "in seconds"
    duration: Int!
    "date and time (local)"
    lastWatched: Date!
  }
```

In play Play Ground, the mutation looks like:

```
 mutation {
  createPlaybackPosition(
    fields: {
      filename: "Test Show.S01E01.Piolet"
      position: 0
      duration: 0
      lastWatched: "06/27/2019 14:22:00"
    }
  ) {
    success
    code
    message
    validationErrors
  }
}
```

When I click the play button I get an error

```
  {
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Expected type Date!, found \"06/27/2019 14:22:00\"; value is not defined",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 2,
            "column": 111
          }
        ],
        "extensions": {
          "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
          "exception": {
            "stacktrace": [
              "ReferenceError: value is not defined",
              "    at GraphQLScalarType.parseLiteral (d:\\Users\\johni\\Projects\\graphql-knex-npvr\\src\\resolvers\\common.js:42:44)",
              "    at isValidScalar (d:\\Users\\johni\\Projects\\graphql-knex-npvr\\node_modules\\graphql\\validation\\rules\\ValuesOfCorrectType.js:175:28)",
              "    at Object.StringValue (d:\\Users\\johni\\Projects\\graphql-knex-npvr\\node_modules\\graphql\\validation\\rules\\ValuesOfCorrectType.js:144:14)",
              "    at Object.enter (d:\\Users\\johni\\Projects\\graphql-knex-npvr\\node_modules\\graphql\\language\\visitor.js:332:29)",
              "    at Object.enter (d:\\Users\\johni\\Projects\\graphql-knex-npvr\\node_modules\\graphql\\language\\visitor.js:383:25)",
              "    at visit (d:\\Users\\johni\\Projects\\graphql-knex-npvr\\node_modules\\graphql\\language\\visitor.js:250:26)",
              "    at Object.validate (d:\\Users\\johni\\Projects\\graphql-knex-npvr\\node_modules\\graphql\\validation\\validate.js:63:22)",
              "    at validate (d:\\Users\\johni\\Projects\\graphql-knex-npvr\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\requestPipeline.js:202:32)",
              "    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\\Users\\johni\\Projects\\graphql-knex-npvr\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\requestPipeline.js:123:42)",
              "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
              "    at fulfilled (d:\\Users\\johni\\Projects\\graphql-knex-npvr\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\requestPipeline.js:4:58)",
              "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If either of the three scalar methods (`serialize`, `parseLiteral` and `parseValue`) returns `undefined`, GraphQL will throw the above error. Returning `undefined` is basically a way of telling GraphQL that the value received is invalid and a validation error should be thrown. You *won't* see the same behavior with `null` since this is a valid value in GraphQL, but you will also see the above error if you return `NaN`.

In this particular case, you're passing `ast.value` to `dayjs`, but this is *not* the value of the string literal you are providing -- it is a ValueNode object like this:

```
{
  kind: 'StringValue',
  value: '06/27/2019 14:22:00',
  block: false,
  loc: { start: 14, end: 16 }
}
```

So you should instead do something like:

```
parseLiteral(ast) {
  if (ast.kind === Kind.STRING) {
    return dayjs(ast.value.value)
  }
  return null
}
```

If you want to always return null if the value is invalid and never throw the validation error:

```
return dayjs(ast.value.value) || null
```